# OpenCV 4.4.0: qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display on a remote EC2 instance. How to solve this issue?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, amazon-ec2

I am running the Opencv 4.4.0 in a Ubuntu 20.04 AWS-Ec2 instance connected with VSCODE trough the Remote Explorer module.

I am trying to open an image that I have uploaded to the project.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("imgs/cat1.jpg")
cv2.imshow("Output", img)
```

But when I run the file (pressing the green arrow) [image] I get the follow error:

```
(env) ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:~/vhosts/opencv-ml-images$ /bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/vhosts/opencv-ml-images/chapter1.py
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Does someone knows what is happening? maybe something related to the fact I am running the opencv in a remote computer? How to sove it?

Comment: Any luck in solving this? I have the same issue running python code directly on ec2.

Comment: FYI, `sudo apt-get install libqt5gui5` did the trick for me

Comment: I decided to abort the Ec2 instance. I couldn't find the solution. I will try yours. Tnks

Comment: Getting same error on ec2,amy solution please help.

Comment: Y can try the computer terminal to run the code. Y can connect trough ssh.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is run it on Remote Desktop Connection. I was having the same problem but I am running WSL 2 (Both are quite similar). And I solved it by setting up environment for GUI applications on WSL 2 from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WSL . Just start your X server and run the code again. It should work. If not, do reply so that we can sort it out together.